# Function unable to get called in click event of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

Unable to access function named print1() in click event of jQuery and it is defined also. I have made a Calculator using jQuery and print1() function prints the value in paragraph tag

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = 0;
    var his1 = "";
    var k = false;
    //flag=false;
    var input = "";
    var prev = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var displayFlag = false;
    var divide = true;
    var firstNumber = "";
    var secondNumber = "";

    $(".number").click(function (e) {
        var num = $(this).text();
        //window.alert(num);
        print1(num);
    });

    function print1(num) {
        // code to print here
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w2h7zLtn/

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/ay7qf4b8/2/. number return 2 times. You need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. You need to move the `print1` to outside of document ready function

[Working link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/ay7qf4b8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var temp=0;
        var his1="";
        var k=false;
        //flag=false;
        var input="";
        var prev=0;
        var count=0;
        var displayFlag=false;
        var divide = true;
        var firstNumber="";
        var secondNumber="";
        $(".number").click(function(e){

            var num= $(this).text();
           //window.alert(num);
             print1(num);
        }); 

});     


function print1(num)
{
    alert(num);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was typing onclick() command code on html page though I had click event in jQuery. Thank you for help !